# Creating Sub Merchant Account in Braintree Sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, braintree

```
 $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
    'merchantAccountId' => 'merchantAccountId',
    "amount" => '45.00',
    "creditCard" => array(
        "number" => 'creditcardnumber',
        "cvv" => 'cvv',
        "expirationMonth" => $_POST["cc_month"],
        "expirationYear" => $_POST["cc_year"]
    ),
    'serviceFeeAmount' => $service_amount,
    "options" => array(
        "submitForSettlement" => true
    )
));
```

I am using [Braintree API](http://developers.braintreepayments.com/). In sandbox i am creating a transaction.
But transaction is not happening. The error is give in below.

```
ERROR! Service fee not supported on master merchant account.
```

But if i comment out following line.

```
'serviceFeeAmount' => $service_amount,
```

Then Order Place Successfully, and i can not see that how much transaction fee is charged.

I want to place order with service fee amount. and the problem is that i am not understanding that how to create **SUB MERCHANT ACCOUNT** on Braintree. Some Answers are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714871/braintree-marketplace-what-happens-if-master-merchant-do-charge-client-at-time)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32520847/braintree-escrow-payment-not-working) given but not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
$validParams = array(
  'individual' => array(
    'firstName' => "Joe",
    'lastName' => "Bloggs",
    'email' => "joe@bloggs.com",
    'phone' => "555-555-5555",
    'address' => array(
      'streetAddress' => "123 Credibility St.",
      'postalCode' => "60606",
      'locality' => "Chicago",
      'region' => "IL",
    ),
    'dateOfBirth' => "10/9/1980",
    'ssn' => "123-00-1234",
  ),
  'business' => array(
    'dbaName' => "Robot City",
    'legalName' => "Robot City INC",
    'taxId' => "123456789",
  ),
  'funding' => array(
    'routingNumber' => "122100024",
    'accountNumber' => "43759348798",
    'destination' => Braintree_MerchantAccount::FUNDING_DESTINATION_BANK,
    'descriptor' => 'Joes Bloggs MI',
  ),
  'tosAccepted' => true,
  'masterMerchantAccountId' => "sandbox_master_merchant_account"
);
    $result = Braintree_MerchantAccount::create($validParams);
```

Here i found this [Braintree_MerchantAccount::create()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/merchant-account/create/php)

Answer (score 0):

you have include  paymentMethodNonce

```
 $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale
([

    'amount' => '10.00',
     'paymentMethodNonce' => 'fake-valid-nonce',
   'options' => ['submitForSettlement' => True]

    ]);

   if ($result->success)
    {
     print_r("success!;".$result->transaction->id);
  } 
  else if($result->transaction)
   {
       print_r("Error processing transaction;");
       print_r("\n code:".$result->transaction->processorResponseCode);
       print_r("\n text:".$result->transaction->processorResponseText);
 }
 else{
   print_r("Validation error:\n");

 }
```